# Requiring a method to be called in a child class constructor

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, constraints

How do I force the Visual Studio compiler to generate an error when a required method is not being called in the constructor of a child class?  Like when you edit the form designer code, the compiler complains when `InitializeComponent()`isn't the first call in the constructor of a form.

Is this even possible in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call that required method in the parent class's constructor?

Comment: I didn't even think about that.  It solves my problem for now, but I need to find a way to avoid duplicate calls to the method I'm requiring.  Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB but maybe you can set a Boolean in the class, set it to true when the method is call and throw an exception if it's false. Just an idea.

Comment: I may have to do something like that to avoid duplicate calls to the method I am requiring, but I've solved my problem of the now a different way.  Thanks for the input!